# want to add qty's to custom options but have nowhere to add extra weight?

Tags: product, product-attribute

I have a product that can be sold as 1 or up to a case which is 4. The drop down allows me to add the qty but not the additional weight. Im I missing something? This is a hazmat item so weight is very important.

Answer (score 1):

Quantity should be additive. If you are tracking each item in inventory (sounds like you are, with a max amount of 4 per order), then as a user adds 2, 3, or 4 to their cart the shipping weight should increase X qty. Are you *not* seeing this?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you configure this product as a configurable product with different qualtity instead of a simple product with custom options.

Comment: I guess I have so many customs that weight is not an option unless it is added as a simple product. @eetzen